# How to invalidate/force update of cache route at next request with Retrofit and OKHttp?

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit with OKHttp client for caching responses from a JSON API.

This works nicely.

However, if I take an action on the device which causes the data to update on the server I need a way to 'invalidate' a particular route in order to ensure that next time a request is made for this data, it is fetched from the server again rather than the now outdated cached version.

Currently, I've worked around this by explicitly calling the new route with a "no-cache" flag in the Cache-Control header of the request, but this forces me to download the new data before it is needed, potentially multiple times if multiple actions are taken, just to keep the cache up to date.

Is there a way I can mark a route / method in my retrofit/OKhttp client as cache expired, requiring a mandatory update over the network the next time it's requested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an API for this, but there should be one. Please [open](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/new) an OkHttp issue to report this.

It'll probably take a while for us to implement because we'll need to figure out what the best API for this is. Invalidating a single URL is straightforward. Invalidating a range of URLs (say `square.com/cash/*`) is more difficult because OkHttp's cache is currently organized by URL checksums. There's also ugly edge cases like what happens if the invalidated URL is currently being written to the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I've created an issue as requested: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/853

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68012702/12528345 for a code sample of the requested feature (the issue mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782531/how-to-invalidate-force-update-of-cache-route-at-next-request-with-retrofit-and/68012702#comment36579273_23784285 was resolved and the feature implemented).

Answer (score 17):

With retrofit2 and OkHttp3 you can force a new response by adding a Cache-Control header to your API method definition parameters:

```
@GET("ws/something")
Something getSomething(@Header("Cache-Control") String cacheControl);
```

and then when calling you either supply `null` for a (maybe-)cached version or `"no-cache"` for a live version:

```
myApi.getSomething(forceRefresh ? "no-cache" : null);
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: this won't cache the refreshed data, how can we cache the refresh data

Comment: Is there any solution to @Sam's comment yet?

Comment: FWIW, in light testing, `no-cache` does not block OkHttp from caching the response. Based on the OkHttp source code, `no-store` would block OkHttp from caching the response.

Answer (score 7):

This is now possible in OkHttp by using the `Cache.urls()` function. As [the documentation](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Cache.html#urls--) says:

> The iterator supports Iterator.remove(). Removing a URL from the
>   iterator evicts the corresponding response from the cache. Use this to
>   evict selected responses.

This was [merged into master](https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/64f2af812bef505b6cbc1693aa8b504d9dbbb42e) late December 2014 and seems to be part of these tags (releases): *parent-2.4.0-RC1  parent-2.4.0 parent-2.3.0 parent-2.2.0*

Answer (score 4):

To quote [the official code sample](https://square.github.io/okhttp/caching/#pruning-the-cache) using `urls()`:

```
val urlIterator = cache.urls()
    while (urlIterator.hasNext()) {
      if (urlIterator.next().startsWith("https://www.google.com/")) {
        urlIterator.remove()
      }
    }
```